# Html to rich text formatting using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a way to convert the rich text to html in Google Sheets. Is there a way to reverse it? HTML to richtext and paste back to cell? Any insights are greatly appreciated.

```
/**
 * Rich Text to HTML.
 * @param {string} qRange Input text.
 * @returns {string} Text as HTML.
 * @customfunction
 */
function RICHTEXT_TO_HTML(qRange) {
  var indexBool = false;
  var indexItalic = false;
  var indexUnderline = false;
  var indexStrikethrough = false;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(qRange);
  var cell = range;
  var cellValue = cell.getRichTextValue();
  var txt = String(cell.getDisplayValue());
  var styles = cell.getTextStyles();
  var result = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    var style = cellValue.getTextStyle(i, i + 1);

    if (!indexStrikethrough && style.isStrikethrough()) {
      indexStrikethrough = true;
      result += '<strike>';
    } else if (indexStrikethrough && !style.isStrikethrough()) {
      indexStrikethrough = false;
      result += '</strike>';
    }

    if (!indexUnderline && style.isUnderline()) {
      indexUnderline = true;
      result += '<u>';
    } else if (indexUnderline && !style.isUnderline()) {
      indexUnderline = false;
      result += '</u>';
    }

    if (!indexBool && style.isBold()) {
      indexBool = true;
      result += '<b>';
    } else if (indexBool && !style.isBold()) {
      indexBool = false;
      result += '</b>';
    }

    if (!indexItalic && style.isItalic()) {
      indexItalic = true;
      result += '<i>';
    } else if (indexItalic && !style.isItalic()) {
      indexItalic = false;
      result += '</i>';
    }

    result += txt[i];
  }

  if (indexStrikethrough) {
    result += '</strike>';
  }

  if (indexUnderline) {
    result += '</u>';
  }

  if (indexBool) {
    result += '</b>';
  }

  if (indexItalic) {
    result += '</i>';
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve your goal, how about the following method?

As a sample method, a Google Apps Script library of "RichTextApp" is used. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/RichTextApp) This library has been created for managing rich text in Spreadsheet.

### Usage:

#### 1. Install Google Apps Script library.

You can see the method for installing this library at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/RichTextApp#1-install-library).

#### 2. Enable Drive API.

This script uses Drive API. So please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services)

#### 3. Sample script.

When your function of `RICHTEXT_TO_HTML` is used, the sample script is as follows.

```js
function sample1() {
  var inputRange = "A1"; // Please set the input range.
  var outputRange = "A2"; // Please set the output range.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###"); // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.

  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // In this case, as the sample, the 1st tab is used.

  // 1. Retrieve HTML from a cell.
  const html = RICHTEXT_TO_HTML(inputRange);

  // 2. Create Google Document by converting HTML to Google Document as a temporal file.
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(html, MimeType.HTML, "sample.html");
  var tempDocId = Drive.Files.insert(
    { title: "temp", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS },
    blob
  ).id;

  // 3. Put the value to a cell as the rich text using the method of "DocumentToSpreadsheet".
  var res = RichTextApp.DocumentToSpreadsheet({
    range: sheet.getRange(outputRange),
    document: DocumentApp.openById(tempDocId),
  });

  // 4. Remove the temporal file.
  DriveApp.getFileById(tempDocId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

### Note:

- This library can use the font size, colors and so on. But, in this sample script, your showing script of `RICHTEXT_TO_HTML` is used. So please be careful this.

### Reference:

- [RichTextApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/RichTextApp)